# How to set indian time zone in web.config file in ASP:NET MVC 5?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

How to set the culture (Indian Standard time) of time zone of an ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

I have tried this in my Modal classes but I want to do this in `web.config` file.

```
private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` add:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture='auto' uiCulture='auto' />
</system.web>
```

Assuming the browser is correctly configured to pass the preferred local, the worker thread processing the request will have its CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture set correctly.

For India time Zone.... I'm assuming 'Hindi Language'

```
<system.web>
       <globalization uiCulture="hi" culture="hi-IN" />
</system.web>
```

For different country which code is used for Culture and time zone you can refer to this link: https://karim-medany.blogspot.com/2012/06/culture-and-ui-culture-for-aspnet-web.html

**Note**:- in this above link, you will find some different type of culture for India so you can refer to one of them.

You can also achieve this using `global.asax`:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-auto");
}
```

You can also set Date format in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
     newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
     newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";

     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 330, GETUTCDATE())
```

By default it will take IST Time Zone

I think this answer will help you....